# Unlocked bootloader, but still cannot boot or flash partitions

Tags: nokia-8

I just had some luck unlocking the bootloader on my Nokia 8.1. But it looks like I've accomplished nothing still. Previously when I attempted to flash a partition via fastboot or boot a boot image, I used to see:

```
flashing is not allowed in locked state
```

Now that I've successfully unlocked the bootloader (I can confirm via deviceinfo command and also via the 5 second warning before boot), I am encountering another roadblock:

```
flashing is not rooted for fused device
```

It appears to be some sort of additional check. The device does show on screen (fastboot mode) that `fuse = enable`. Looks like this is some additional check for devices which have been unlocked  to prevent unauthorised use. I do not have any idea how to disable it. It probably comes from the Kernel level or probably somewhere else. Can somebody guide me to a direction which I should take next?
There should be some way to disable fuse.